# Facebook mutual friends

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

I am trying to sort my friends by the number of mutual friends we have. I tried getting the number of mutual friends one by one and creating an id->no_of_mutual_friend key value pair but that just takes way too long, because I have to call the facebook API over a 1000 times.

Is there an easier way to do this by using FQL?

Comment: Not a duplicate, Cthulhu; they're very different questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This do what you need?

```
SELECT uid, mutual_friend_count
FROM user
WHERE uid IN 
    (SELECT uid1 
     FROM friend 
     WHERE uid2 = me()) 
ORDER BY mutual_friend_count DESC
```

Comment: yes thank you, much more faster